# Update TextView Automatically in Android

Tags: android

I have a default folder to store a file which is created by user.

[image]

I want to update the Output Path automatically when user type in the output name, they do not have to click on the button OK in order to show a full output path. Is there any ways to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this on your own yet?

Comment: textview.settext("ur output path")

Comment: I think about check the Output Name every 1 second or milisecond and update the Output Path, but it is not a good solution. I think it has another better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the outpath's name is '`a`' and the outputpath is `b`. Use this:

```
a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != -1)
        //edited here
        b.setText(a.getText());
   }
  });
```

Basically you are listening for textchanges in the editext where you want the information from, and then adding it to the 2nd texview

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However, we should change if condition to (s.length() != -1). If not, when we input "output.mp4" in Output Name and then remove it, letter "o" in "output.mp4" will not be removed.

Comment: you can just remove the whole if condition too.